# sqlite error message in visual studio 2013 system.io.fileloadexception

Tags: vb.net, vba, sqlite

i'm a home schooled code writer, not very technical. i'm trying to access an s3db file with sqlite in visual studio 2013 using VB. i keep getting this error message 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in sqlite.exe

Additional information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information."

code is below, the debugger points to loadpropertydata()

Imports System.Data.SQLite
Public Class listboxpropertydata

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    loadpropertydata()

End Sub
Public Sub loadpropertydata()
    Dim connectionString As String = "data source=c:\users\andy\documents\a la mode\database\spectrum.s3db"
    Dim mSQL As String = "select AD_ADDR1, AD_ADDR2, PR_SALEPR1, SC_SOURCE1, SC_SOURCE2, FN_CONC1,FN_CONC2, DT_SALTIM1, LC_LOCAT1, RG_RIGHTS, ST_SITSIZE, ST_SITEVW,DA_DESAPL1, DA_CONSTQL, AG_AGYRBLT, AG_COND1, RM_TOTAL, RM_BED,RM_BATH, SF_GLA, BM_BSM1, BM_BSM2, FU_FUNCTUT, HC_HTCOOL, EE_EFFIC1,CR_GARPRK1, PF_PORPAT1, BL_BLANK1, BL_BLANK2, BL_BLANK3, HS_PRIOR1,HS_PRIOR2, HS_PRIOR3, HS_DSDATE from TOTALFormSource"
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Try
        Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(mSQL, con)
                con.Open()
                Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    dt = ds.Tables(0)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        listboxsqlresults.valuemember = "PropertyGrid"
        listboxsqlresults.displaymember = "Address"
        listboxsqlresults.datasource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Please get some details from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

You have to use version specific components. For dotnet 4.0 applications, you have to use sqlite build on dotnet 4.0

You should install

For 32 bit App

http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.94.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.94.0.exe

OR

For 64 bit App

http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.94.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x64-2010-1.0.94.0.exe

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please mark this as answer?

Comment: i don't know how to do what you are asking me to do